# Error when run RInside example in eclipse

Tags: r, eclipse, rinside

Greeting,

I'm trying to run RInside examples in eclipse, but I have this error

```
./rinside_sample0.o: In function `main':
D:\omnetpp-5.1\samples3\myRapp\Debug/../rinside_sample0.cpp:16: undefined reference to `RInside::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
D:\omnetpp-5.1\samples3\myRapp\Debug/../rinside_sample0.cpp:18: undefined reference to `RInside::parseEvalQ(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:46: myRapp.exe] Error 1
```

here is the code for rinside_sample0:

```
#include <RInside.h>                    // for the embedded R via RInside

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    RInside R(argc, argv);              // create an embedded R instance

    R["txt"] = "Hello, world!\n";   // assign a char* (string) to 'txt'

    R.parseEvalQ("cat(txt)");           // eval the init string, ignoring any returns

    exit(0);
}
```

I added the following configuration in eclipse:
[image]
[image]

Any help to figure out how to solve this problem will be very appreciated

Comment: Did you try following these steps?: http://blog.fellstat.com/?p=170

Comment: yes, that gives me the following error ```./src/main.o: In function `main':
D:\omnetpp-5.1\samples3\MyRInsidePackage\Debug/../src/main.cpp:9: undefined reference to `rcpp_hello_world'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:47: MyRInsidePackage] Error 1
 ```@MrFlick